# jpackage not Command 'jpackage' not found, did you mean: command 'package' from deb mailagent Try: sudo apt install <deb name>

Tags: java, jpackage

```
java --version                                                                                                               
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on-Dswing.aatext=true
openjdk 17.0.2 2022-01-18 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-17.0.2.8.1 (build 17.0.2+8-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-17.0.2.8.1 (build 17.0.2+8-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)


when i run the comand jpackage i got this Error
```

Comment: Need more info. What happened to produce this message?

Comment: We know what happens when this guy runs Java. We do not know what happens when this guy runs jpackage. But it seems there is a wrapper script between the call and the actual JVM.